Google Apps Script designed for multiple users
I have developed a GAS that is designed for multiple users at a time.
The app executes under my Google account.
Each user logs into the system, it does a very basic validation and gets a specific sheet to use for that particular login.
I store this information in a variable using sessionStorage. At different points I have to reference this variable to re-access the particular sheet.
I’m seeing data from one user in the sheet of another user.
From what I can tell all of this should be specific to each user. So, I’m confused and concerned.
What am I missing and what can I do to stop this from happening?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Try using PropertiesService userProperties().  Also provide [mcve] if you expect a more detailed answer

That is often what one finds when creating the [mcve]

Thank you for the response. I wish I knew what part of my code was causing the problem. I posted hoping someone has had the same type of issue and had a resolution. I’ll try the ProperitesService as suggested. But, since this is sporadic and not reproducible on demand, it makes it very difficult to track down.

Without the [mcve] we cannot produce the problem so that makes it difficult to fix.

Anyone experiencing this issue? I have now tried the propertiesService and when a second user accesses the app and an updated variable with the same name  is written with PropertiesService it doesn’t overwrite the other users variable. Which doesn’t make sense. I have tested this on two computers side by side. 1) First user logs in. 2) then second user logs in. 3) First user enters data into the gui and saves the record to the sheet. 4) screen  refreshes as designed. 5) sheet assigned to the second user is then displayed on the first users screen. This is crazy I’m not sure what else to try.

Is it published? (i mean your gas script) or all your users have view or edit permissions to acces your script.

Please provide a [mcve] or we can't help.  I've used user properties before and they are not shared so you are probably doing something wrong.  Create a [mcve] and quit wasting our time.

Cooper: if I’m wasting your time, stop responding to my messages. This is a place where people can ask questions and there is no need for you to be rude. I see your profile says you can be a PITA…I have always had very positive interactions here and people have been very helpful. For some reason you latched onto my thread and became a real PITA. Please stop.
